# Can a QTcpSocket release its descriptor

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

Is it possible for a QTcpSocket to release its descriptor so ownership over the socket **can be transferred** to another QTcpSocket object on a different thread, or to a QSslSocket, **without closing/interrupting** the socket?

```
socket1.setDescriptor(descriptor);

// .....

descriptor = socket1.descriptor();
socket1.release();                       // <--- Is there a way to do this?
socket2.setSocketDescriptor(descriptor);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't release a socket descriptor once it has been assigned to a `QTcpSocket`.

But I'm not sure you would need to. The `QTcpSocket` can usually be moved to another thread with `moveToThread`, the constraints are the same as any moved `QObject`:

- `moveToThread` should be called inside the thread to which the object currently belongs,
- the object can't have a parent (you can remove it with `theObject->setParent(0);`, or move the parent instead of the object),

and because it is a `QTcpSocket`, the receiving thread should be running an event loop or you need to use the `waitFor...` functions in that thread.

[This note](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#note-33) seems to suggest that this only works for sockets since Qt 4.7.